# Add a field to all events with a specific ID in splunk

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I'm trying to add a field to all log lines of an event which has some ID associated with it. The first log line has some information that I would like to propagate all the way to a field in the last log line. How would one do this? It would be good to be able to do it as a field extraction, or something like that.

Comment: Please give a specific example of what you want to do. Sounds like it should be possible using regex and eval commands.

Comment: So you want to create a unique identifier for each event as a field?